# Polyglossia setotherlanguage conflicts with tikz library quotes

Tags: tikz-pgf, polyglossia

When I use tikz with the quotes package in a graph environment to add a label to an edge (as I found out here: [Label on edges with tikz-graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310207/label-on-edges-with-tikz-graph)) I get problems as soon as I specify an otherlangue with polyglossia.

I've seen other people reporting similar issues with the babel package: [problems with tikz and arabi package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124314/problems-with-tikz-and-arabi-package) and [Adding a TikZ figure to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38595/adding-a-tikz-figure-to-a-document). In both cases the solution was to switch to English but that does not help in this case.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{english}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \graph {
        "A" -- "B" [> "some label"]
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{english}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"{some label}"' and I am 
going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14       }
            ;
?
```

The XeLaTeX version is: XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)

pgf version is: 3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

According to what I find adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` fixes it. I use an updated TeXLive 2019 installation with pgf v3.1.5 and checked both `lualatex` and `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
  \begin{english}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \graph {
        "A" -- "B" [> "some label"]
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{english}
\end{document}
```

[image]